# JDBC results set iteration sometimes goes fast and often times goes slow (75x speed difference)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, jdbc

I'm developing a GAS script to retrieve data (~15,000 rows) from an Azure SQL database table into a Sheets spreadsheet. The code works fine but there are **huge** speed differences from run to run in the results.next() loop

Below is my code (some variable declarations and private stuff removed) and below the code is logs from three executions

```
function readData() {

    Logger.log('Establishing DB connection')
    let conn = Jdbc.getConnection(connectionString , user, userPwd);

    Logger.log('Executing query')
    let stmt = conn.createStatement();
    let results = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM VIEW");


    let contents = []
    let i = 0

    Logger.log("Iterating result set and adding into array")
 
    while (results.next()) {
        contents.push([
        results.getInt(1),
        results.getString(2),
        results.getInt(3),
        results.getString(4),
        results.getInt(5),
        results.getString(6),
        results.getString(7),
        results.getString(8),
        results.getFloat(9),
        results.getFloat(10),
        results.getInt(11),
        results.getString(12),
        results.getInt(13),
        results.getInt(14),
        results.getInt(15),
        ])

        //Make log entry every 100th iteration and display the average passed ms per iteration 
        i++
        if(i % 100 == 0){
            Logger.log(i)
            finish = new Date().getMilliseconds();
            Logger.log((finish - start) / i)
        }
    }



    sheet.getRange(2,1,sheet.getLastRow(),15).clearContent()

    sheet.getRange(2,1,contents.length,15).setValues(contents)

    results.close();
    stmt.close();
}
```

Fast run:

```
8:41:47 AM  Info    11100 Records added
8:41:47 AM  Info    8.43ms on average per record
8:41:47 AM  Info    
8:41:47 AM  Info    11200 Records added
8:41:47 AM  Info    8.42ms on average per record
8:41:47 AM  Info    
8:41:48 AM  Info    11300 Records added
8:41:48 AM  Info    8.42ms on average per record
```

Slow run:

```
8:48:01 AM  Info    100 Records added
8:48:01 AM  Info    162.30ms on average per record
8:48:01 AM  Info    
8:48:17 AM  Info    200 Records added
8:48:17 AM  Info    162.84ms on average per record
8:48:17 AM  Info    
8:48:34 AM  Info    300 Records added
8:48:34 AM  Info    163.11ms on average per record
```

Extremely slow run:

```
8:56:46 AM  Info    300 Records added
8:56:46 AM  Info    629.08ms on average per record
8:56:46 AM  Info    
8:57:49 AM  Info    400 Records added
8:57:49 AM  Info    628.95ms on average per record
8:57:49 AM  Info    
8:58:52 AM  Info    500 Records added
8:58:52 AM  Info    629.70ms on average per record
```

So as seen from above logs, one run of the script can go roughly 75x faster than another. The time per iteration stays the same within a specific run. I'm pretty baffled as to how that's possible. Is there something about the result set object I don't know?

Comment: You're running your application in one cloud (Google's) against a database in another cloud (Microsoft's). The performance difference can come from anything, from difference of load of the node your application is running on, saturated network connections, geographic differences, and this applies to both sides. I'd first consider those differences before blaming the driver.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I would definitely agree with you if it wasn't for the fact that the iterations can run for a half an hour with a constant iterating speed. Most recent run was 630ms/iteration (+- 1,5ms) until the GAS 30min cutoff. 

If it was a case of one or both of the cloud instances receiving sudden instantaneous loads (and thus slowing down) it would make sense for the iteration pace to fluctuate within a single run, but it doesn't. If the first 100 iterations take 600ms/iteration then the iterations 15min later in the same run will also take 600ms/iteration

Comment: Have you checked if removing the iteration and doing it in another function, gathering the results from the query and then treating them in another function after the connection is closed does change the runtime?

Comment: @Kessy I don't quite follow exactly what you mean. The iteration IS where I'm gathering the results and IT is the thing that is taking way too long.

Comment: @Kessy I have attempted to modify my code such that it completely closes and reopens the connection if the iterations are taking too long. However even this doesn't help and the iteration speed stays the same regardless of making a new connection within the same GAS-script execution. 

It's as if there was a random number generator that determines if the script will be fast or slow when it is run

Answer (score 0):

You can submit a bug on [Google's Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/) using the following template for Apps Script:

- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191640&template=823905

If you have a workspace account, you can also contact [Google Workspace support](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213?hl=en&fl=1) so they can take a look at your issue.